# Node.js memory leak in a docker environment on production servers

Tags: node.js, docker, memory, memory-leaks, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
node --version
  v10.15.1
```

I have a memory leak that causes the heap to run out of memory and the garbage collector to not be able to do its job.

I am using Node 10 running in a docker container on AWS Elastic-beanstalk. I attempted to capture a heap-dump locally (on my machine) and on other environment (less traffic) and it does not show any findings.

In production, the node is crashing after 14 hours of up-time with `--max-old-space-size=4096`.

I can't alter the code in production to profile at runtime, is there a way to connect to the server and go into the docker container to collect a heap-dump of the running process?

Deploying new code to perform profiling is not an option so far.
Any other ideas are appreciated, what make it difficult is the constraint of the environment receiving production traffic and making the memory leak not reproducible in any other environments.

Thanks,

Comment: did you find a way?